# Linq - Remove one anonymous list from another

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've seen many answers to this - but can't seem to get them to work:

```
 var numinqtoday = bc.SSRecs.Where(x => x.DateTime == id).Select(n => new
       {
           refer = n.@ref
       }).GroupBy(x => x.refer).ToList();

 var numinqprev = bc.SSRecs.Where(x => x.DateTime < id).Select(n => new
       {
           refer = n.@ref
       }).GroupBy(x => x.refer).ToList();


 var filtered = numinqtoday.Except(numinqprev).ToList();
```

In my code above:

```
 numinqtoday.Count() = 184
 numinqprev.Count() = 155

 filtered.Count() = 184
```

I have checked and there are definitely occurrences within numinqprev within numinqtoday - so it appears the .Except isn't removing them before putting in filtered.

Could anyone advise please where I'm going wrong?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got a list of *groups* there - and I suspect you'll find that one group is never equal to another. I suspect you want to perform the `Except` operation *before* the grouping. For example:

```
var numinqtoday = bc.SSRecs.Where(x => x.DateTime == id).Select(n => new
   {
       refer = n.@ref
   }).ToList();
var numinqprev = bc.SSRecs.Where(x => x.DateTime < id).Select(n => new
   {
       refer = n.@ref
   }).ToList();
var filtered = numinqtoday.Except(numinqprev).GroupBy(x => x.refer).ToList();
```

Another option would be to create a set of keys, and use `Where`:

```
// Code as per your original, including the GroupBy calls. Change the string
// part as per the type of refer, which we don't know...
var keys = new HashSet<string>(numinqprev.Select(g => g.Key));
var filtered = numinqtoday.Where(g => !keys.Contains(g.Key)).ToList();
```

Also note that if you've only got one property, there's not much point in using an anonymous type.

Comment: Perfect - thank you - I'll mark as the answer in 7 mins - cheers, Mark

Comment: 3 min, you're quick. I was still writing my answer :)

Comment: Hi - the reason for the anonymous type is the bc.SSRecs is the table in the database - and it contains more than just the one column (@ref) that I'm interested in.  So I thought I had to project that table into a new table, just containing the property I was interested in?  If I'm wrong, I'd really appreciate if you could advise further?  Cheers, Mark

Comment: @MarkTait: You can just use `Select(n => n.@ref)` and get a sequence of strings (or whatever the type is). No need to use an anonymous type.

Comment: @ConradClark You got Skeeted ;-).